# How can I position nested lists side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1g49g2t/7/

I want the ol and ul items to be next to eachother. Is this possible?

Structure:

```
<ol class="level1">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>
        <ul class="level3">
          <li>item3</li>
          <li>item3</li>
          <li>item3</li>
          <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: First of all, make sure to close all the tag, the ol isn't close. What do you mean by next to each other ? You don't want the indent right ? Have you try by adding left:0; to ul li like here https://jsfiddle.net/a1g49g2t/2/ ?

Comment: @BrunoLandowski What I want, is that the ul and ol tags float next to eachother, horizontally.

Comment: I can works using float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ol ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a1g49g2t/10)**

Note that the top-level list could be positioned relatively for easier page layout. It doesn't matter as long as it's not left at the default (`static`).